# Excel Crashes after but not while running macro to copy formatting of chart to another chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I wrote a macro that copies the format of one chart object and pastes it into other chart objects. The macro SUCCESSFULLY completes and the newly made chart objects are correctly made. It does what it's supposed to! However, Excel crashes immediately upon saving or after fiddling with the new chart object. It crashes in both Excel 2010 and Excel 2016.

I have isolated the code snippet that causes the Excel crash. In the following snippet of code, if Lines 8-9 are commented out, Excel does not crash:

```
For Each cht In sh_plots.ChartObjects
    With cht.Chart

    'copies master chart format
    master_plot.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

    'applies formats
    .ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=2
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

So these 2 lines (8-9) are the ones at fault:

```
.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=2
```

Does anyone know why these 2 lines are acting as the bane of my existence right now? I have tested these 2 lines multiple times, and the crash is reproducible. My excel file is not corrupt because I tried to copy the code as text to a new Excel file and used safe mode etc etc, still crashing.

I do not want to have to copy the master chart property by property to accomplish the same thing as this simple format paster - unless someone has a better idea, that would require so much more extra code!

I have the Event Viewer error log if that would shed any light. Thanks!

Comment: I think the way I've done this is to copy the first (formatted) chart, then change the data in the copy so that it shows the data in the second chart. Hopefully changing the data does not mess up the formatting: if it's a problem, go to File tab > Options > Advanced > Chart, and uncheck "Properties follow Chart Data Point for Current Workbook."

Answer (score 0):

Untested, as am on mobile. But I don't think you need to activate/select to copy-paste.

Code below toggles events and screen updating.

```
' Ensure you have Option Explicit and have declared cht as a ChartObject '

With application
.screenupdating = false
.enableevents = false
End with

'copies master chart format
        master_plot.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

For Each cht In sh_plots.ChartObjects

    'applies formats
    Cht.chart.paste type:=xlformats

Next cht



'reset property outside of loop - once all done. '
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

With application
.screenupdating = true
.enableevents = true
End with
```

Comment: I assume that you want to apply the master chart's formatting to all charts on sh_plot; so makes sense to copy only once and then paste until no more ChartObjects to loop through. Whether this will fix what causes the crash, I don't know.

Comment: This approach used to work just fine in Excel 2003, but it was broken in Excel 2007, and the broken behavior has by now become the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved the problem by  messing around with more stuff!

For some reason Excel crashes if you specify error bars before pasting the chart format. So I did not specify error bars until after I pasted the format. Really weird that it does this.